# DataGridView loading of data has a poor UI performance, despite threading

Tags: c#, multithreading, datagridview

I've already created a thread for my datagridview to improve the performance
but I can still see the lag and unresponsiveness of my project. All I want is to run this smoothly. 
And one more question, if there's a bulk of data in my datagridview, should I create a loading stuff to trick the user?

Look out and see my code , Did I make it right? or should I do something better?

```
public studentManager()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        ThreadStart thread1Start = new ThreadStart(LoadGrid);
        Thread t1 = new Thread(thread1Start);
        t1.Start();
    }



 public void LoadGrid()
    {
        if (radGridView1.InvokeRequired)
            radGridView1.Invoke(new Action(() =>
            {
                //For Buttons stuffs
                add.Image = Properties.Resources.adde;
                add.Enabled = true;
                delete.Image = Properties.Resources.deleted;
                delete.Enabled = false;
                update.Image = Properties.Resources.updated;
                update.Enabled = false;
                errorProvider1.Clear();

                //Datagridview
                MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(MyConnectionString);
                connection.Open();
                try
                {
                    MySqlCommand cmd = connection.CreateCommand();
                    cmd.CommandText = "Select * from studenttable";
                    MySqlDataAdapter adap = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                    adap.Fill(ds);
                    radGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0].DefaultView;

                    label8.Text = "Student Information loading completed!";

                    radGridView1.Columns[0].HeaderText = "Student Number";
                    radGridView1.Columns[0].Width = 100;
                    radGridView1.Columns[1].HeaderText = "Name";
                    radGridView1.Columns[1].Width = 300;
                    radGridView1.Columns[2].HeaderText = "Section";
                    radGridView1.Columns[2].Width = 50;
                    radGridView1.Columns[3].HeaderText = "Email";
                    radGridView1.Columns[3].Width = 100;
                    radGridView1.Columns[4].HeaderText = "Course";
                    radGridView1.Columns[4].Width = 50;
                    radGridView1.Columns[5].HeaderText = "Gender";
                    radGridView1.Columns[5].Width = 150;
                    radGridView1.Columns[6].IsVisible = false;
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    throw;
                }
                finally
                {
                    if (connection.State == ConnectionState.Open)
                    {
                        connection.Clone();
                    }
                }
            }));
        else
        {
            label8.Text = "Data information is loading........";
        }


    }
```

Please notify me if there's wrong with my question because I am new here in stackoverflow. Thank you :D

Comment: Use BeginInvoke instead of Invoke

Comment: Not directly related, but notice you are calling connection. _Clone_ () instead of `Close` inside your `finally()` block.

Comment: opening a `SqlConnection` might be taking some time. also threading doesn't ensure better performance automatically. In your case, the major work is data retrieval from database. its gonna take same time to complete irrespective of your application threading logics.

Comment: Using Invoke will make sure code is executed on UI thread thats why your UI Freezes....Moreover, you need to identify which part of your code is taking time.....is it SQL query or data binding itself..If it is sql query then move the sql query in seperate thread and once you have the data you call begininvoke to update UI....if it is data binding it self then you may have to implement paging